# How do I use webform tokens in my PHP code for the form submission page?

Tags: 7, webforms

I see this in webforms, but I don't know how to use these in my result page, as `print_r(%value)` doesn't print anything.

> Submission tokens
>
> `%sid` - The unique submission ID.
>   `%value[key]` - A value without additional formatting. Elements may be accessed such as `%value[fieldset_a][key_b]`. Do not include quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These won't show up in the results page.  I think these are only useable when the form is submitted.  One thing that confused me for a while was the [fieldset].  If the value you are trying to access is not in a fieldset it is [Root].

Name:  ***_*_**

%value[Root][name]  would be most likely way to access that value after the form is submitted by the user.

(%email works also if you are going to send an email, but that also shows the label)

Hope this helps and is actually what you need help with.

-Marc

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are not PHP variables.
Using PHP functions won't have any effect.

Not sure how current this information is, but this page tells how to get the webforms submitted data in 6.x.

http://drupal.org/node/236515